# Difference between app:srcCompat and android:src in Android's layout XML

Tags: android, android-imageview, layout-xml

Whenever I create an ImageView with icon added using Android Studio's Vector Assets, I'm getting an error at the line `app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_play"`

When I change the `app:srcCompat` with `android:src`, the error is gone but the icon looks pixelated.

What is the main difference between

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_play"
```

and

```
android:src="@drawable/ic_play"
```

Answer (score 174, accepted):

**[app:srcCompat](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)**

> is the most foolproof method of integrating **[vector drawables](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html)** into your app.Vector drawables allow you to replace multiple png assets with a single vector graphic, defined in XML. While previously limited to Lollipop and higher devices

**Note**

As of **[Android Support Library 23.3.0](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/iTDmFiGrVne)**, ***support vector drawables*** can only be loaded via **`app:srcCompat`** .

you need to add **vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true** to your `build.gradle` file

```
    // Gradle Plugin 2.0+  
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
 }
```

**[android:src](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:src)**

> Sets a drawable as the content of this ImageView.It will display in
> its original size. No automatic scaling .

Comment: the error with app:srcCompact is gone when added vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true in Gradle app module

Comment: Will app:srcCompat conflict with older android versions? More specifically Api 19 being the oldest version i'm referring to.

Comment: Wow can finally get rid of bitmap icons.

Comment: Google Plus post link is now dead

Comment: I've added above to `build.gradle`, but it's still not working, any ideas?

Comment: Thank you, i tried weeks to understand how to stop gradle generating this pngs

Answer (score 38):

If you are using `android:src="@drawable/some_vector"` without `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` in build.gradle file and your app have vector images (vector drawable), then while building the *apk* file Android gradle plugin generates a lot of *.png files for different screens (hdpi, xhdpi...) from each of your vector drawable (only for API =< 19). The result - bigger size of *apk*.

When using `app:srcCompat="@drawable/some_vector"` with `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` android uses vector drawable files without generating `*.png` files.

You can check this with Android Studio apk analyzer tool. Just build apk with and without `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`.

I think this is the main difference.

Comment: So if you have useSupportLibrary set to true, why do you need the special syntax, rather than android:src= ? If you use android:src= with useSupportLibrary activated, do you avoid the proliferation of PNGs?

Answer (score 12):

**Use:**

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/backImage"
```

***The srcCompat attribute is actually defined within AppCompat library.
Important: you will need to add the appropriate namespace for this.***

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

**Note**

What you are getting seems to be just a lint error that can be ignored. I have tried and gotten the same error, but it is working correctly.

You can use `tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"` to avoid seeing this error, temporarily.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

```
app:srcCompat="some_resource"
```

is refer that it is AppCompatActivity src which comes in support library while

```
android:src="some_resource"
```

refers to simple activity.

Comment: this was Insightful.

Answer (score 4):

Vectors and animated vectors were only supported in recent versions of the framework.  srcCompat can be used with the compatibility library to make them work, but this only works with the certain views in the support library.  Notice that app: is used instead of android:.  This means its not part of the framework, but a parameter defined by your app.

Answer (score 3):

Android 5.0 (API level 21) and higher provides vector drawable support so in order to support vector drawables in older versions app:srcCompat was added