# ImageView (logo) not showing in 2nd Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imageview

In android Studio I have 2 activities. 1st is a login screen with my logo. the 2nd is details, with my logo. in the studio everything looks ok, but when testing on my phone, it displays everything except for my imageView (logo). I have tried, different images, different positions. I have even cut and paste the layout code from my main activity (which works fine). Nothing works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="1">

        <!-- Login progress -->




    <TextView
                android:id="@+id/longitude"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action_name"
        android:layout_weight="0.42" />

    <TextView
                android:id="@+id/latitude"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/longitude"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/driver"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/location"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/location"
        android:layout_below="@+id/latitude"
        android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.02" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try using background in place of app:srcCompat or use only android:src

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
android:src="@drawable/ic_action_name"
```

It will set your drawable as the content of this ImageView.

Comment: that actually worked... interesting.. the properties does not give a src option. But thanks very much

Comment: If want to know the difference between them then check out the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624554/android-what-is-the-difference-between-appsrccompat-and-androidsrc