# My XML File does not display anything

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I dont understand Why nothing appears on the display. I can see the Button and the ImageView (zauberer) but otherwise nothing.. can someone help me?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/halbtransparent">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/dialoghintergrund"
        android:id="@+id/willdialog"
        android:layout_margin="20dp" />


    <ImageView
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:id="@+id/zauberer"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/zaubererdialoghg"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_width="43dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_verstanden"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="410dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/btn_verstanden"/>
```

Comment: I think your problem is `srcCompat` as said in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624554/android-what-is-the-difference-between-appsrccompat-and-androidsrc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of suggestion:

1. `fill_parent` is deprecated use `match_parent`
2. use `android:src` instead of `app:srcCompat`
3. you are using static Dp values `android:layout_marginTop="410dp"` which will be varied in different devices according to pixel density.

use `layout_weight` , `weightSum` , `adJustViewBounds` , `Gravity` to align your views..

4. Best practice to use different size `drawable` iamges in your `mdpi` , `hdpi` , `xhdpi` etc folder.

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/willdialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/zauberer"
        android:layout_width="43dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_verstanden"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Okay thank you! When i use now android:src must i change in my Java Activity now "AppCombatActivity" to "Activity" ? Or is this no matter?

Comment: no it is not necessary...you can still use `AppCompatActivity` in code

Comment: When i want to change android:background to android:src in my xml is the background transparent

Comment: <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="310dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/dialoghintergrund"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
            android:layout_height="500dp">

Comment: `android:src` is for imageview or imagebuttons... if u want to set transperant background use: `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: Okay :) But on some devices i cant see the background..why?

Comment: check your drawable image is it suitable for all screens? try to resize the image in hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi etc...folders

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is displayed in `Activity` or Android Studio? Have you closed the `Framelayout` tag? try to use `Relativelayout`. Make sure you have `setContentView` in your `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because child layouts in FrameLayout overlap each other and the child written at the bottom is drawn over the others. Use LinearLayout with orientation set to vertical to resolve the problem.