# Is there still any difference between android:src vs app:srcCompat?

Tags: android

I read about `app:srcCompat` on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624554/android-what-is-the-difference-between-appsrccompat-and-androidsrc) and also from other resources that the main purpose of this attribute is to support for vector-drawable. But I got confused when `android:src` is also working fine with vector-drawable.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M10.18,9"/>
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M21,16v-2l-8,-5V3.5c0,-0.83 -0.67,-1.5 -1.5,-1.5S10,2.67 10,3.5V9l-8,5v2l8,-2.5V19l-2,1.5V22l3.5,-1 3.5,1v-1.5L13,19v-5.5l8,2.5z"/>
</vector>
```

I saved the above code in `abc.xml` file in drawable directory, then I use it with `android:src`

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:src="@drawable/abc" />
```

It is working fine. Then where app:srcCompat is helpful or is there any difference between them? or I understand it wrong?

Comment: What is your `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`? What version of Android is on your test device or emulator?

Comment: Emulator's android version is 7.0

Comment: This is why you do not see a difference. Vector drawables were introduced with Nougat.

Comment: Ooh great let me confirm you mean app:srcCompat is for older android versions? because older verion's android:src was not working with vector?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice can you help me to find the difference? I mean which android version should I use to check the difference? help me to choose the following versions. which minSdkVersion? which targetSdkVersion? which Emulator's Android Version? which Project's Version?

Comment: Sorry, VectorDrawable was introduced in Lollipop API 21. If you create an AVD for an API version prior to this, you should see the difference. (What @riggaroo said)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference. There is an article [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) about it.
Basically `app:srcCompat` will work on older APIs when loading up vector drawables. You’ll find directly referencing vector drawables outside of `app:srcCompat` will fail prior to Lollipop, you are probably running the `android:src` on Lollipop or higher.

Comment: Great thanks. Can you answer on my other question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/43014279/2769917 I really struggling to find the purpose of android:ems.

Answer (score 0):

For devices running Android 5.1 or lower, I have found that it's not safe to replace usages of `app:srcCompat` with `android:src`. For example, this vector file renders blurred:

[image: blurry app:srcCompat vs better android:src]

*Running on Android 5 - left:* `android:src` *right:* `app:srcCompat`

On devices running SDK 23 (ie, Android 6.1) or higher however, I had no problems using `android:src` instead of `app:srcCompat`.

See documentation for VectorDrawableCompat [here](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/graphics/vector-drawable-resources#vector-drawables-backward-solution).