# Android ImageView won't load on CustomList with ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-viewholder

I have a custom list view which I recently upgraded to use View Holder. Right now the project works fine but the images in the two Image Views don't show on the screen.

[image]

This two black icons appear "transparent" but work if I click them.

This is the layout:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgInfo"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.04"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/details64" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgInfo"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgEdit"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgInfo"
                android:layout_weight="0.24"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtChamado"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtSolicitante"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtItemDeCatalogo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgEdit"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.03"
                android:contentDescription=""
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/pencil64" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the code snippet:

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {

        View convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (view == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.customized_list_view, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            convertView = view;
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //  Object declaration
        final Sette setteData = getItem(position);

        //region Put the Tasks values to the textviews
        // Get me two strings, one with the older value and one with the newest
            String oldChamado = holder.txtChamado.getText().toString();
            String newChamado = setteData.getChamado();
            // Do not repeat the string in the textview
            if (!(oldChamado.equals(newChamado))) {
                holder.txtChamado.setText(newChamado);
            }
     //region Click Listener for the button that leads to Approvals Activity
        if (!aBoolean) {
            holder.imgEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    chamadoClicked = setteData.getChamado();
                    solicitanteClicked = setteData.getSolicitante();
                    itemDeCatalogoClicked = setteData.getItemDeCatalogo();
                    id = setteData.getId();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), ApprovalsActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Id", id);
                    intent.putExtra("chamadoClicked", chamadoClicked);
                    intent.putExtra("solicitanteClicked", solicitanteClicked);
                    intent.putExtra("itemDeCatalogoClicked", itemDeCatalogoClicked);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
        //endregion
 return convertView;
    }// END METHOD
```

ViewHolder (which I got from an internet example):

```
  public class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtChamado;
    TextView txtSolicitante;
    TextView txtItemDeCatalogo;
    ImageView imgInfo, imgEdit;
    Typeface bebasKai;
    Typeface london;

    public ViewHolder(View view){
        bebasKai = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/bebaskai.otf");
        london = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/london.ttf");
        txtChamado = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtChamado);
        txtChamado.setTypeface(bebasKai);
        txtSolicitante = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSolicitante);
        txtSolicitante.setTypeface(london);
        txtItemDeCatalogo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtItemDeCatalogo);
        txtItemDeCatalogo.setTypeface(london);
        imgEdit = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgEdit);
        imgInfo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgInfo);
    }
}
```

*I tried clean, rebuild, download the project from BitBucket again, reinstall the app from scratch on my phone, invalidade cache/restart and check the code.*

**Am I missing something obvious here?**

**EDIT:**Thank you SaNtoRiaN, I knew it was something simple that I was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `app:srcCompat` attribute in your `ImageView` to `android:src` to view your images properly. To know more about the difference, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624554/android-what-is-the-difference-between-appsrccompat-and-androidsrc) answer.

Comment: OMFG! I knew it was something stupid. Thank you so much bro. XD