# ImageView shown in designer's preview but not showing when I run app

Tags: android

I am scratching my head with this...I have this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.company.app.LoginActivity"
android:background="@color/rojo">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/conway"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etusername"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="@string/username"
    android:background="@color/blanco"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etpass"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etusername"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etusername"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="@string/password"
    android:background="@color/blanco"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tventrar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="@string/sendlogin"
    android:textColor="@color/blanco"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etpass"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvlostpass"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/lostpass"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textColor="@color/blanco"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>


<View
    android:id="@+id/shade"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blanco"
    android:visibility="invisible" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Its a very simple login screen. I have an ImageView on top of the screen...but I can't see it when I run my app in a device. Why is that? How can I get my ImageView?

Thank you.

Comment: are you using correct xml inside your activity ?

Comment: Yes I am...I can see all other components, but the ImageView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of:

```
 app:srcCompat="@drawable/conway"
```

use:

```
 android:src="@drawable/conway"
```

`srcCompat` attribute is defined within AppCompat library.

To know more about their difference Go through this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624554/android-what-is-the-difference-between-appsrccompat-and-androidsrc)

Comment: It is showing now...thank you. Will up vote within 10 minutes.