# android.view.InflateException when use an imageview

Tags: android, layout, imageview, inflate-exception

im trying to put an imageview at the top to show a logo but when i run the app i have this error:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error
>   inflating class android.widget.ImageView

if i delete that imageview the code runs without a problem

how i can solve this here is activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#2e3138"

    tools:context="dattasolutions.cloud.dattasolutionscloud.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
  >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:id="@+id/tvHeading"
        android:text="Presiona el icono para subir archivos al servidor"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivAttachment"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/attach_icon"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_x="145dp"
        android:layout_y="171dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_file_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivAttachment"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/b_upload"
        android:text="Upload"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="#039be5"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Is your image a vector icon or png?

Comment: Look further down in logcat. You should see another error that points to the real problem. Post that error here if you don't understand what is going on.

Comment: png image and its only 400kb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to Replace. 
         `android:src="@drawable/logo"`

With.
        `app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"`
See [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624554/android-what-is-the-difference-between-appsrccompat-and-androidsrc).

And if it still doesn't work then check the size of the image. Some times it is not actually the inflating problem but a deeper one i.e. Memory issue leading to inflation exception. Use an image with minimum necessary size.
Hope it helps.

Comment: app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" leads to an error but android:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" doesnt,besides it doesnt show the image

Comment: Try to test using a different image with smaller size.

Comment: the size of the image is near 400kb

Comment: Any thing relevant in log? And did you tried a different image?

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem is in your image named "**logo**" try some other image and check whether it's the problem of **image format or size** etc. In this way you'll **easily** come to know about the problem and what type of image should you use in the **future**. Good Luck!