# Image is not loading

Tags: java, android, imageview

I was wondering why the image here is not loading at all. The XML file does not show the image, it does however show the `TextView` and the `Button`.

Please help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="177dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Middle Right Pop Up" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/small_circle"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/small_compass" />

</LinearLayout>
```

,

```
public class PopUpMiddleRight extends Activity{

    ImageView compass;
    private float currentDegree = 0f;
    private static SensorManager sensorService;
    private Sensor sensor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pop_up_middle_right);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams windowManager = 
getWindow().getAttributes();
        windowManager.dimAmount = 0.75f;

getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

        int width = dm.widthPixels;
        int height = dm.heightPixels;

        getWindow().setLayout((int)(width * .8), (int)(height * .6));

    }

}
```

I am trying to make a pop up window so it would look something like this: [image: PopUpWindow]

Also Please note that I am referencing the image in another place in my code, so it can read the image.

Comment: use src instead of src compat

Comment: whats the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace
  `app:srcCompat="@drawable/small_compass"` to `android:src="@drawable/small_compass"` instead

Comment: What is the difference

Comment: You can get answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624554/android-what-is-the-difference-between-appsrccompat-and-androidsrc)