# Why is my ImageView not showing the image?

Tags: android, imageview

Trying to display an image using `ImageView` but it's not being displayed.
The source image is kept in the `drawable` directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constrainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.485"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/nature"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Try using `app:srcCompat="@drawable/nature"` instead of `tools:srcCompat="@drawable/nature"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tools:srcCompat="@drawable/nature"` is using for showing the image in design time. When you need to see it on run time, you should add `android:src="@drawable/nature"` as below in your `ImageView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constrainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.485"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/nature"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/nature"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of using

```
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/nature"
```

use

```
        android:src="@drawable/nature"
```

Comment: Thanks Wini,It worked :),would you please tell me what is the difference ?

Comment: please check my answer it explained the difference

Comment: @UbaidKhan any property prefixed with `tools:` is ignored at runtime

Comment: @UbaidKhan for more explanation --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624554/difference-between-appsrccompat-and-androidsrc-in-androids-layout-xml

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

`tools:srcCompat="@drawable/nature"`

by

`android:src="@drawable/nature"`

Answer (score 0):

Development time only attributes -> `tools:`

Production level (runtime) attributes -> `android:` and `app:`

At run-time tools attribute will removed. so You have to replace that attribute with `android:src`.

`tools:srcCompat="@drawable/nature"`  **->** `android:src="@drawable/nature"`