# Don's see an ImageView using Inflater

Tags: java, android

I have made XML markup for part of my program.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/checked_border">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/asset_icon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_dollar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/asset_name_and_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/asset_icon"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="count" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="sum" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

After that, I tried to add it using inflater

```
LayoutInflater ltInflater = getLayoutInflater();
        RelativeLayout assetlayout = (RelativeLayout)
                ltInflater.inflate(R.layout.asset_layout, null, false);
        LinearLayout assets = findViewById(R.id.assetslayout);
        assets.addView(assetlayout);
```

So that what I expected to see. Also, you can see a top margin.

[image: Expected]

But when I run my program I don't see an image view and there are no top margins at all.

[image: Result of using Inflater]

Comment: I would suggest, you add your code as text instead of images

Comment: can you show what is the output you are getting ?

Comment: I attached an output. Is's the last screen shoot

Comment: I have updated my answer using a code instead of photos

Comment: have you tried enabling the use of vectorDrawables since you are using srcCompat : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40624625/6224662

Comment: I have tried  to do that but it doesn't work

Comment: can you post code of the recycler view you are using to create the shown view?