# Image in dynamic view is not displaying

Tags: java, android-studio

When I click the add button to add a new view, everything but images are displaying on the screen. I tried different images in different positions. But nothing worked.

```
    public void onClick(View view) {

        LayoutInflater vi = null;
        vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        
        View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.news_views, null);
        
        ViewGroup insertPoint = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.allNews);
        insertPoint.addView(v, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    }
```

This is the method I am using and news_views is the layout I am using to add a new news on the main screen.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlYT0.png)

To show that it is actually there I added a background color.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoRJB.png)

And also when there is no background it makes space, so it is there but not really :/

This is the .xml file of the news_views:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/news_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/grey_round"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Heading Is Just Right Here"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:text="This is going to be a preview for the user to understand what is about this article."
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/upvoteIcon"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="2"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float" />
```

Comment: Hello and welcome! Your question looks to be pretty good. I think it would be very helpful to answerers and future readers if you made your title more specific. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind the error is in news_views.xml file. The vector drawable is tried to be set as source of ImageView using **srcCompat** attribute. If it is intended to use **srcCompat** attribute, build.gradle file should contain
`vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`
line of code.

Or **src** attribute may be used instead of **srcCompat** attribute.

It is indicated and explained in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624554/difference-between-appsrccompat-and-androidsrc-in-androids-layout-xml). You can look at the link for more information about the **src** and **srcCompat** .

Comment: Yeah, it worked thanks man. But I had to change the app to android also:
```android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float" />```

Comment: When I used a png image instead of a svg, it worked.